# RecylerView Adapter onCreateViewHolder & onBindViewHolder not called: view empty

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm using `RecyclerView`, `CardView`, `Fragment` and `AsyncTask` in an Android version 23 project in Android Studio. I'm attempting to debug the app on a Samsung Galaxy S7. No matter what I seem to try codewise, the `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` methods of my `RecyclerView.Adapter` implementation class never get called.

Activity:

```
public class RecyclerViewFragmentActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.todays_visit_list_container);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            RecyclerViewFragment fragment = new RecyclerViewFragment();
            transaction.replace(R.id.sample_content_fragment, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {
    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    protected RecyclerViewAdapter mAdapter;
    protected ListRefresher aListRefresher;

    protected class ListRefresher extends AsyncTask<Uri, Void, Void> {
        private ArrayList<Probationer> probationers = null;
        RecyclerViewFragment fragment = null;

        public ListRefresher(RecyclerViewFragment fragment) {
            this.fragment = fragment;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Uri... params) {
            ArrayList<Probationer> probationers = new ArrayList<Probationer>();
            // getData makes a JSON call to retrieve data for RecyclerView Adapter
            listobjects = getData();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            fragment.onTaskCompleted();
        }

        public ArrayList getItems() {
            return probationers;
        }

    }

    protected void onTaskCompleted() {
            PPOTodaysVisitListAdapter adapter = new PPOTodaysVisitListAdapter(getActivity(), aListRefresher.getItems());
            mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.todays_visit_list, container, false);
        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
            LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
            llm.scrollToPosition(0);
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);
            mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            aListRefresher = new ListRefresher(this);
            aListRefresher.execute();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private ArrayList<Probationer> probationers;
    Context context;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Probationer> probationers) {
        this.probationers = probationers;
        this.context = context;
    }

        public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public CardView cv;
            public TextView supervisionLevel;
            public TextView popCodes;
            public TextView unavailable;
            public TextView offenderId;
            public TextView name;
            public TextView birthDate;
            public TextView addressLine1;
            public TextView addressLine2;
            public TextView lastDrugScreen;
            public TextView lastDrugScreenResultNeg;
            public TextView lastDrugScreenResultPos;
            public TextView mainCrime;
            public TextView lastDate1Lbl;
            public TextView lastDate2Lbl;
            public TextView lastDate3Lbl;
            public TextView lastDate4Lbl;
            public TextView lastDate1;
            public TextView nextDate1;
            public TextView lastDate2;
            public TextView nextDate2;
            public TextView lastDate3;
            public TextView nextDate3;
            public TextView lastDate4;
            public TextView nextDate4;

            MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                    super(itemView);
                    cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
            supervisionLevel = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.supervisionLevel);
                    unavailable = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.unavailable);
                    popCodes = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.popCodes);
                    .
                    .
                    .
            }
        }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        //Inflate the layout, initialize the View Holder
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.todays_visit_list_item, parent, false);
        RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder = new RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder(v);
        return holder;

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        if (probationers != null && probationers.size() > 0) {
            Probationer aProbationer = probationers.get(position);
            if (aProbationer != null) {
                viewHolder.offenderId.setText(aProbationer.getProbationerId());
                viewHolder.name.setText(aProbationer.getName());
                viewHolder.birthDate.setText(aProbationer.getDateOfBirth());
                viewHolder.supervisionLevel.setText(aProbationer.getSupervisionLevel());
                viewHolder.unavailable.setText(aProbationer.getUnavailable());
                .
                .
                .
         }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return probationers.size();
    }
}
```

RecyclerView layout (todays_visit_list.xml):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

CardView layout (todays_visit_list_item.xml):

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <RelativeLayout 
            android:id="@+id/photolayout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip">   
            <ImageView  
                android:id="@+id/loadingphoto"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:src="@drawable/nopicture"/>
            <ImageView  
                android:id="@+id/photo"
                android:scaleType="fitEnd"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/supmsglayout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="72dip"
            android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
            android:layout_below="@id/photolayout"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@id/photolayout">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/supervisionLevel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="6dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dip"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/unavailable"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/supervisionLevel"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/supervisionLevel"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/popCodes"
                android:layout_width="76dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textColor="#E79A00"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_below="@id/supervisionLevel"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/supervisionLevel"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/contentlayout"
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="300dip"
            android:layout_height="100dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/photolayout"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/photolayout">
            <TextView android:id="@+id/offenderIdLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Offender ID: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/offenderId"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/offenderIdLbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/offenderIdLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/nameLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Name: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/offenderIdLbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/offenderIdLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/nameLbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/nameLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/birthDateLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Birth Date: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/nameLbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/nameLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/birthDate"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/birthDateLbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/birthDateLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/addrLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Address: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/birthDateLbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/birthDateLbl"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addressLine1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/addrLbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/addrLbl"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/addressLine2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/addressLine1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/addressLine1"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDrugScreenLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Drug Scr: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/addressLine2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/addrLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDrugScreen"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastDrugScreenLbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/lastDrugScreenLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDrugScreenResultNeg"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastDrugScreen"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/lastDrugScreen"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDrugScreenResultPos"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:textColor="#d7144b"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastDrugScreen"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/lastDrugScreen"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/mainCrimeLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Crime: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDrugScreenLbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDrugScreenLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/mainCrime"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mainCrimeLbl"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/mainCrimeLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate1Lbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="33dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/mainCrimeLbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mainCrimeLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate2Lbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="34dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/mainCrimeLbl"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastDate1Lbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate3Lbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="86dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/mainCrimeLbl"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastDate1Lbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate4Lbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="140dip"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/mainCrimeLbl"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/lastDate1Lbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Last: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate1Lbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/mainCrimeLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/nextLbl"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Next: "
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastLbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastLbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate1Lbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate1Lbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/nextDate1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate1"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate1"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate2Lbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate2Lbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/nextDate2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate2"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate2"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate3Lbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate3Lbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/nextDate3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate3"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate3"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/lastDate4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate4Lbl"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate4Lbl"/>
            <TextView android:id="@+id/nextDate4"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="11sp"
                android:layout_below="@id/lastDate4"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@id/lastDate4"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/undolayout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="40dip"
        android:layout_height="100dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/contentlayout"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/contentlayout">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/undo_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/button_undo"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My JSON call is returning data, and the `AsyncTask` is calling back to the `Fragment` and executing method `onTaskCompleted()`. When I create the instance of `RecyclerViewAdapter`, the `ArrayList` contains items. The only problem is that the `RecyclerView` never displays anything. The `onCreateViewHolder` and `onBindViewHolder` methods of `RecyclerViewAdapter` never get called.

I've played around with the `layout_width` and `layout_height` of all elements of both layouts, thinking that somehow that was causing the problem. I've also purposely called `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the `RecyclerViewAdapter` after instantiating it and before setting it in the `RecyclerView`. Also no joy there.

Does anyone see any glaring problem here that could be causing the `RecyclerView` not to render?

I'm also curious as to what actually triggers the calling of these two methods on the adapter... if I can figure that out, maybe I can determine why the event isn't being triggered.

Comment: Are you creating a custom adapter?

Comment: Yes I have a custom adapter. It is the class named RecyclerViewAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the adapter to the RecyclerView earlier on the lifecycle (onCreate is a good choice), and when your AsyncTask is done only notify the adapter via `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Also, make sure you set a LayoutManager, like this:

`recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));`

Since your RecyclerView lives inside the fragment, in your case will be:

`recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));`

Regarding your question

> I'm also curious as to what actually triggers the calling of these two
>   methods on the adapter... if I can figure that out, maybe I can
>   determine why the event isn't being triggered.

it has to do mostly with your dataset size when the time to render the list arrives. In your case (and once mine), missing to set the LayoutManager, somehow, causes not to render either.

You already have a reference to the context in your adapter, can you try to do:

```
@Override
    public RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.todays_visit_list_item, parent, false);  //
        RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder holder = new RecyclerViewAdapter.MyViewHolder(v);
        return holder;    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried setting the adapter with an empty ArrayList into the RecyclerView in the onCreateView method of my Fragment, and then notifying the adapter that the dataset had changed after my AsyncTask completed, but still nothing is rendered. I did notice though, that the following warnings/errors are in the console: W/DisplayListCanvas: DisplayListCanvas is started on unbinded RenderNode (without mOwningView)
E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null                                  Could this be a clue?

Comment: Did you set a LayoutManager also?

Comment: Yes I was already doing                                                                                   LinearLayoutManager llm = new       LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
            mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(llm);